# descriptor '__dict__' for objects doesn't apply to object using type()

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, inheritance

I'm getting weird behavior when using `type()` in Python 3.6+. I am using it to dynamically wrap all classes from an external library, and am getting an error when calling `self.__dict__`.  Consider the following example:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print(self.__dict__)

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__()

B() # this works
```

but when I do the equivalent thing using `type` I get this weird error:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print(self.__dict__)

class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__()

# C is a class which is B that inherits from A
C = type('C', (A,), B.__dict__.copy())
C()
# TypeError: descriptor '__dict__' for 'B' objects doesn't apply to 'C' object
```

How do I fix this with using `type()`?

[TLDR: @fritzo's answer fixes the error but this design introduces other inheritance issues. The accepted answer by @juanpa.arrivillaga gives a better workaround]

Comment: Different issue, but never pass `self.__class__` or `type(self)` to `super` - [it breaks as soon as you create a grandchild class](https://ideone.com/TRZ9av).

Comment: I need that in the non `__init__` methods or I get `TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type`.

Comment: That error does indeed happen. Grandchildren are designed to work, though, and what you're doing is not. What you're doing is incompatible with `super`, and breaks in a ton of other cases, not just with `super` or `__dict__`. You should really redesign your wrapper; if you don't, the problems will just keep piling up, especially as the external library changes.

Comment: Depending on the context of the rest of your program, the right solution might be to give your `C` a `B` instance as an attribute, or to make `A` a mix-in and multiple-inherit from `A` and `B`.

Comment: So I tried using mixins but I couldn't get the functionality I wanted. Suppose I have a method `foo()` from a class C(B, A)  where B is my mixin and A is an external class. In `foo()`, I'd like to check if an attribute exists and invoke `B.foo` else invoke `A.foo`.  But in B, I don't have access to the class (and methods) of A. This is straightforward for one class by writing it out without `type` but I'd like to do this programmatically for all of them. How can I write this?

Comment: I think I would probably put that check in the code that creates `C`, rather than in `B`. (I might not have `B` at all, in fact.) When you're creating `C`, you have full access to `A`. You can put whatever functions you want in `C`'s dict based on inspecting `A`.

Comment: I don't follow. `C` (as written in the OP) is just B derived from A. It could easily be written as `B = type('B', (A,), B.__dict__.copy())` which is renaming B to be the class that inherits from A. I don't see a way to dynamically construct classes that can do what you're saying besides what I have above. I can't write a derived class a priori without knowing the parent class. `type()` is the only way to do it AFAIK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments on wanting to do this *dynamically*, you *could* use `super` but you have to understand how it works, `super` gives you *the next method in the method resolution order*, so you *do* have access to the methods in `A` from your mixin, but you have to use `super` correctly: so something like this could work:

```
In [1]: class Mixin:
   ...:     def foo(self):
   ...:         if hasattr(self, 'whatever'):
   ...:             print("doing Mixin.foo stuff")
   ...:         else:
   ...:             return super().foo()
   ...:

In [2]: class A:
   ...:     def foo(self):
   ...:         print("doing A.foo stuff")
   ...:

In [3]: class C(Mixin, A):
   ...:     pass
   ...:

In [4]: c = C()

In [5]: c.foo()
doing A.foo stuff

In [6]: c.whatever = 42

In [7]: c.foo()
doing Mixin.foo stuff
```

However, I'm not sure how recommendable this is. But it's possible.

Note, and by dynamic, I mean something like this works:

```
In [9]: class Mixin:
   ...:     def foo(self):
   ...:         if hasattr(self, 'whatever'):
   ...:             print("doing Mixin.foo stuff")
   ...:         else:
   ...:             return super().foo()
   ...: class A:
   ...:     pass
   ...:
   ...: class B:
   ...:     def foo(self):
   ...:         print("doing B.foo stuff")
   ...:
   ...: class C(Mixin, A, B):
   ...:     pass
   ...:

In [10]: c = C()

In [11]: c.foo()
doing B.foo stuff

In [12]: c.whatever = 42

In [13]: c.foo()
doing Mixin.foo stuff
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I have a bunch of different `A`s I am loading, so the only way to do that programatically (AFAIK) is with `C = type('C', (Mixin, A), Mixin.__dict__.copy())` which is about what i have in the OP.  However I get type errors in the `super().foo()`, with the TypeError in the comment above. I can resolve it with `super(self.__class__, self)`, but then thats undesirable per our conversation above.

Comment: @luxon it would help if you gave a full and complete description of the actual issue you are facing. This is a class example of the [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Ah yes, I meant `C = type('C', (Mixin, A), {})`. I had an issue calling `super()` with this earlier but I believe this solution works. Thanks!  I'll edit and accept your response; I try to avoid editing the OP because others may be looking to just debug the error message with a different problem.

Comment: Let me restate my high level problem. There is an external library with a bunch of classes that share a common parent. I want to override some methods in *every* class, so that they do custom logic if a conditional is satisfied, otherwise use the original logic.  There can be new classes added in this upstream library so I want to do this dynamically (so in your example imagine there is {A_1, A_2, ... A_n} where n is the number of classes)

Comment: @luxon then you can just use a class definition statement. `for cls in list_of_classes: class X(Mixin, cls): pass;` etc